# Trying to convert id prop to mongoose ObjectId

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose

this is my function:

```
 acceptContactRequest: async (
      _: any,
      { userId }: IUserInfo,
      context: ExpressContext
    ) => {.....}
```

IUserInfo:

```
export interface IUserInfo {
  username: string;
  password: string;
  userId: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId;
}
```

this is what I am trying to do:

```
   userAuth?.pendingRequests.filter(
        (requestId) => userId !== requestId
      );
```

requestId output is new ObjectID(id)

and userId output is only the id.

I tried to convert it like this :

```
 userAuth?.pendingRequests.filter(
        (requestId) => mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId) !== requestId
      );

  userAuth?.pendingRequests.filter(
        (requestId) => ObjectId(userId) !== requestId
      );
  userAuth?.pendingRequests.filter(
        (requestId) => new ObjectId(userId) !== requestId
      );
```

but none of them is work. I always get this error:

```
ObjectId' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here
```

Thank you!

Edit:
requestId is coming from here
[image]

I want to match that id with userId..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not directly use `ObjectId` s for comparison, have to convert into string.

```js
import { Types } from 'mongoose'

export interface IUserInfo {
  username: string
  password: string
  userId: Types.ObjectId
}

// assuming both `requestId` and `userId` here are ObjectId
userAuth?.pendingRequests.filter((requestId) => '' + userId  !== '' + requestId)
```

Comment: Hi, the problem is userId is not an objectId.. it's just a number

Comment: and If I am turning requestId(which is ObjectID) for string I will get ['id']

Comment: @עמיתשוקרון got it, you need to fix `requestId` first, can you update question with where exactly `requestId` is coming/generated.

Comment: Edited, it's coming from pendingRequests from User

Comment: @עמיתשוקרון what does this outputs `console.log(userAuth?.pendingRequests[0].toString(), '' + userAuth?.pendingRequests[0])
`

Comment: 62ef949904c3585404cd7c00

Comment: its working, but why did you say _"i am turning requestId(which is ObjectID) for string I will get ['id']"_ in prev comment

Comment: because I tried to do it like this :
   console.log(
        userAuth?.pendingRequests.map((requestId) => requestId.toString())
      );
and I got ['id']

Comment: are you sure, double checked it ??, it should be  `['62ef949904c3585404cd7c00']` not `['id']`

Comment: Oh I mean ['62ef949904c3585404cd7c00'], I typed ['id'] because I am too lazy.. sorry

Comment: @עמיתשוקרון oh ok, should have used `[<ObjectId>]`. Anyway now explain why `userId` is number,  if you compare them with `requestId` there is good change it will be always `false` because `userId` is a 'decimal' number not 'hexadecimal' number.